# Is it possible to load XML contents into WebView2 (similar to WebBrowser)?

Tags: xml, xslt, visual-c++, browser, webview2

I want to upgrade the browser from WebBrowser to WebView2 in our existing application (written in Visual C++).

Using WebBrowser, I normally loaded images in a tabular format (arranged by defining in XSL).
Also I could able to do operations(like Image drag and drop) within this table using JS(with DOM architecture).

By upgrading to WebView2, I want to able to do the same operations as above(In WebBrowser).

I just tried below things,

1. Created instance of ICoreWebView2.
2. Invoked ICoreWebView2->Navigate(url)
   Here I passed local path of XML file.
   Tried with below code before CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(),

```
options->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"--allow-file-access-from-files
```

")

I want to provide the same support using WebView2 by replacing WebBrowser.
Anybody please provide suggestions, is this possible to do ?

Comment: It might be easier, in the end, to run any XSLT transformation you need with your C++ code first and then simply to render the result of the XSLT transformation in the WebView2 control.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. I had one more query. For WebView2 case, as you said I need to do XSLT transformation before rendering in WebView2 control. But for WebBrowser, I am not doing this transformations. ie. xml file path is directly passed to WebBrowser.Navigate(file.xml). For WebView2 case, this is not working. ie. WebView2.Navigate(file.xml) not works. Can you please clarify my doubt ?

Comment: As you found, simply navigating to an XML file doesn't work to get an XSLT stylesheet applied. I am not familiar with all settings of WebView2, perhaps wait if some experienced user comes along and gives you an answer to just use a setting so that you can navigate to an XML file. On the other hand, I would think that writing some lines of code to perform the XSLT transformation with your code and use NavigateToString https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2?view=webview2-1.0.2045.28#navigatetostring might be faster than hoping there is a setting.